# how to join 2 results for show in a result

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hi i have two query :
this is for select list :

```
select *  from buy
```

Buy tables :

```
ID | product_id| Time
```

and i want to add text for every records, this is query for select text for every records

```
Updated
```

final result is something like this

```
    {
        "ID": "13",
        "product_id": "4",
        "Date": "2016-10-28 00:00:00",
        {
            "txt_1": "hi this is txt 1",
            "txt_2": "this is txt 2"
        }
    }
```

for that result i use from this code :

```
    $result = $con->executeNoneQuery($sql_1);//get all records
    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
        $result2 = $con->executeNoneQuery($sql_2);//get txt for every records
    }
```

now i want to know can i get both result with one sql query ? or any better idea ?
something like this

```
    {
        "ID": "13",
        "product_id": "4",
        "Date": "2016-10-28 00:00:00",
        "txt_1": "hi this is txt 1",
        "txt_2": "this is txt 2"
    }
```

**Update :**
Sorry I'm confused with real second query
secend query is this :

```
select txt from product_id,text_list where text_list.id=product_id.id and product_id='a1' order by rand() limit 2
```

Comment: You shouldn't use any mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since php 5.5 and completely removed in php 7.0

Comment: @Manish ok,Thanks, I can replace `mysql_` with `mysqli_`, however have any solution for my problem ?

Comment: I am agree with @arunkn28. you can the use this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query :

```
SELECT t2.*,GROUP_CONCAT(t.text SEPARATOR '###') as txt 
FROM buy t2 
LEFT JOIN txt t on t2.id = t.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_id p on t.id=p.id
where t.product_id='al' 
GROUP by t.product_id
```

And after that in your PHP code you try that :

```
$txts = explode("###", txt);
```

To get array of text fields for every row

Answer (score 0):

Flow bellow code :

```
Select b.ID,b.product_id,b.Time,t.text from buy b RIGHT JOIN text t ON p.product_id = t.product_id;
```

Comment: From what I have understood from your question it should work. Please try it.

Comment: why you are used `RIGHT JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected query is :

```
Select a.id,a.product_id,a.Time,b.txt_1, b.txt_2 from 
buy a LEFT JOIN text b ON a.id = b.product_id order by rand() limit 2;
```

more details http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: i saw your second updated query. your first table name is `buy` but what is your second table name?